# Best way to query different xml elements as one column

Tags: xml, postgresql

I have a xml field with similar name elements that I have to query as one, they change some capital letters, something like:

```
/cfdi:Comprobante/@tipoDeComprobante
/cfdi:Comprobante/@TipoDeComprobante
```

where only initial "t" is different

I am currently using CTEs, coalesce() and full joins to query them as single columns, making a pass for every variant

but I can´t get them all in a single pass, avoiding CTEs, if I use

```
select unnest(xpath('/cfdi:Comprobante/@tipoDeComprobante', f.xml, ARRAY[ARRAY['cfdi'::text, 'http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3'::text]]))::text tipo,
       unnest(xpath('/cfdi:Comprobante/@TipoDeComprobante', f.xml, ARRAY[ARRAY['cfdi'::text, 'http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3'::text]]))::text tipo2 from web_factura_proveedor f
```

gives me null values for their counterparts

```
 tipo tipo2
 text text
 "I", [null]    
 "I", [null]    
 "I", [null]    
 "I", [null]    
 "I", [null]    
 "I", [null]    
 "E", [null]    
 [null], "I"
 [null], "I"
```

I couldn't cast them to text to coalesce them.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a test case in MS SQL Server. Two attributes with one character difference. The idea is to use upper-case() function. Please take a look, it may give you some point of reference what to try in postgresql.

> SQL

```
DECLARE @xml XML = 
N'<root>
    <age type="one" Type="two" different="three">25</age>
</root>';

SELECT @xml.query('<output>{
for $x in /root/age
return $x/@*[upper-case(local-name(.))="TYPE"]
}</output>');
```

> XML

```
<output type="one" Type="two" />
```

Comment: thanks @Yitzhak but I am using Postgresql,lower(f.xml::text)::xml made the trick, is it the fastest?